# Finding top searched country and ip from a table

Tags: postgresql, count

I have a table "user" with columns ip,os,country and browser. I want to find the ip,os,country and browser with maximum count.Is there any query for that in PostgreSQL

The current query I'm using is

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT COUNT(ip),ip FROM user GROUP BY ip 
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(os),os FROM user GROUP BY os 
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(country),country FROM user GROUP BY country 
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(browser),browser FROM user GROUP BY browser
) user
```

it shows all ip,os,country and browser and their count
what i really want is a column name the max count of that column

is it possible to do that in a single query?

Im expecting something like this

```
os      count           ip              count
linux     50         xx:xx:xx:xx      95
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: and if two categories have same counts?..

Comment: @ Vao Tsun it'll be shown separately

Comment: Something like `SELECT COUNT(ip),ip FROM user GROUP BY ip ORDER BY 1 DESC LIMIT 1`?

Comment: excatly but with more than one column

Comment: sample data with expected result will be helpful

Comment: @ Oto Shavadze 
i have provided the expected result in description

Comment: if 2 (or more) ip  have same max counts, then which one should output ?

Comment: select any one of the ip that will be  enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT COUNT(ip) as cnt_ip, ip FROM user GROUP BY ip ORDER BY 1 DESC LIMIT 1) as t_ip,
  (SELECT COUNT(os) as cnt_os, os FROM user GROUP BY os ORDER BY 1 DESC LIMIT 1) as t_os,
  (SELECT COUNT(country) as cnt_country, country FROM user GROUP BY country ORDER BY 1 DESC LIMIT 1) as t_country,
  (SELECT COUNT(browser) as cnt_browser, browser FROM user GROUP BY browser ORDER BY 1 DESC LIMIT 1) as t_browser
```

Comment: this solution will ignore the items with the same count

Comment: @RadimBača Yes, according to the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45753241/finding-top-searched-country-and-ip-from-a-table/45754363?noredirect=1#comment78465542_45753241).

Answer (score 1):

You may use `HAVING` and `ALL` for that. Due to readability purpose, I'll show just for one column

```
SELECT COUNT(ip),ip 
FROM user 
GROUP BY ip 
HAVING COUNT(ip) >= all
(
  SELECT COUNT(ip)
  FROM user 
  GROUP BY ip 
)
```

Comment: can u show me with  2 columns?
I'm having some trouble

Comment: and you want a maximum count for each column or maximum count across all columns? maybe some example output for sample data would be useful.